# Difference between integer and set of vectors in prometheus/grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I can't realize how to figure out with metrics `nss_chan_last_seq` and `nss_chan_subs_last_sent`. I need to get difference between `max(last_seq)` and `min(last_sent)` for every `durable_name`
So i have metric last_seq:

```
max(nss_chan_last_seq{channel="some-channel", instance=~"some-cluster-cl.*"}) by (channel)
```

And last_sent:

```
min(nss_chan_subs_last_sent{channel="some-channel", durable_name=~"durable-name-s.*", durable_name!~".*test"}) by (channel, durable_name)
```

And when I put something like this:

```
max(nss_chan_last_seq{channel="some-channel", instance=~"some-cluster-cl.*"}) by (channel) - on (channel) min(nss_chan_subs_last_sent{channel="some-channel", durable_name=~"durable-name-s-.*", durable_name!~".*test"}) by (channel, durable_name)
```

I got this error:

```
execution: found duplicate series for the match group {channel="some-channel"} on the right hand-side of the operation: [{channel="some-channel", durable_name="durable-name-s16"}, {channel="some-channel", durable_name="durable-name-s14"}];many-to-many matching not allowed: matching labels must be unique on one side
```

Can someone please explain me, how to figure out with this?

I tried to play with on(), group_left(), and group_left() ok with one vector in `nss_chan_last_seq`, but i have several durable_names for one channel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the query is that the instant vector from the left-hand side operand has multiple matches on the right-hand side instant vector operand.

In such cases, you must explicitly tell Prometheus how do you want to match the time series.

#### Group Modifiers (group_left, group_right)

[Group modifiers](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#group-modifiers) enable **many-to-one (group_left)**/**one-to-many (group_right)** vector matching.

To make sure all the "many side" labels are preserved, the result has all the labels from samples on the operand on this "many side", which is the left side for **group_left** and the right side for **group_right**.

So:

- if the "many side" is a left-hand side operand --> use **group_left**.
- if the "many side" is a right-hand side operand --> use **group_right**.

---

Let's take your operands.

**Left**-hand side operand:

`max(nss_chan_last_seq{channel="some-channel", instance=~"some-cluster-cl.*"}) by (channel)`

```
{channel="fizz"} 1
{channel="bazz"} 2
```

**Right**-hand side operand:

`min(nss_chan_subs_last_sent{channel="some-channel", durable_name=~".*"}) by (channel, durable_name)`

```
{channel="fizz", durable_name="foo"} 10
{channel="bazz", durable_name="foo"} 20

{channel="fizz", durable_name="bar"} 30
{channel="bazz", durable_name="bar"} 40
```

The "many side" is the **right**-hand side operand, so **group_right** should be used:

```
max(nss_chan_last_seq{channel="some-channel", instance=~"some-cluster-cl.*"}) by (channel)
- on (channel)
min(nss_chan_subs_last_sent{channel="some-channel", durable_name=~".*"}) by (channel, durable_name)
```